# jQuery datatable yadcf column filter issue when column reorder is applied

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I'm using jQuery datatable 1.10.16 and jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js 0.9.1. Below are my datatable functionalities,

1. server side data
2. SHow/Hide columns - colvis
3. State Save and State Load in server side
4. ColReorder
5. Column filter (yadcf)

Column filter is **NOT** required for all the columns. It is required for few specific columns. Everything is working fine except, the column filter is not working for some fields after I do a column reordering. For eg:

```
dhboardtable = $('#table').DataTable({.....});

yadcf.init(dhboardtable, [
                    ...........
                   {
                      column_number: 11,
                      filter_type: "text",
                      filter_delay: 2000
                    },
                    {
                        column_number: 13,
                        filter_type: "text",
                        filter_delay: 2000
                    },
                    {
                      column_number: 14,
                      filter_type: "text",
                      filter_delay: 2000
                    }
```

Column index 12 does not need the filtering(as per requirement). So, I didn't have the column index 12 in the yadcf initialization. The issue is when I drag and drop (reorder) the column 14 (or any columns index > 12) to position it before column 12 (no filter column), then column 14 filter is not working.

Could someone please help with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the latest beta version of yadcf

in addition look at the [showcase page of server side](http://www.yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html) and set the `"columns"` property for the table and use `stateSave":  true`.

it should work with the above setup

Comment: The DataTable already has the "columns" property and stateSave set as true. I tried with both versions 0.9.2 and 0.9.3 beta. The issue is still not resolved. Here is the error that I see in the browser console, 
"TypeError: yadcf.getOptions(...)[column_number] is undefined". As I mentioned in my previous post, there are a few columns that does not need to have the column filter. So, the issue is when I drag-drop a column with filter option, to the left of a column without filter, the moved column's filter is not working after that drag-drop operation.

Comment: @LGeo maje sure you assign name to the data in the columns, if still no good provide a link to your test case